# How to iterate "Cost Path as Polyline" tool using ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python, cost-path, least-cost

I have an optimization GIS problem to be solved. I want to use genetic algorithm to solve it in Python so I have to iterate  my script many times. Recently i have realized that "Cost Path as Polyline" tool which i have used in my script, results in empty feature classes, However when I implement the tool manually in ArcMap 10.6.1, it works properly with the same datasets. My script is too long to write it down here. The following code is similar to my code and leads into the same problem. 
Do you know why this happens or know a solution?

```
import random
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace=r'G:\PTest.gdb'
arcpy.env.outputCoordinateSystem=arcpy.Describe("Wetland").spatialReference
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

def createlines():
    fcname="points1"
    i=1
    while arcpy.Exists(fcname):
        fcname="points"+str(i)
        i=i+1

    arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management('G:\PTest.gdb',fcname,'POINT')
    cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fcname, ["SHAPE@XY"])
    for t in range(4):
        cursor.insertRow([(random.randint(1263153,1275580),random.randint(792226,804579))])
    arcpy.sa.CostPathAsPolyline(fcname,
                                'cost_distance',
                                'cbacklink_raster',
                                'lines_'+fcname,
                                'EACH_CELL',
                                'OBJECTID')

for x in range(4):
    createlines()
```

Comment: Try to set extent to cost or backlink raster.

Comment: Are your input rasters in the PTest file geodatabase?

Comment: I think you should delete insert cursor before doing line.

Comment: I don't think it is related to extent of raster since "cost path as polyline" function works properly with same datasets in arcmap. If you need i can send you datasets @FelixIP. Also i couldn't figure out how deleting insert cursor may help. Can you please explain why?

Comment: Yes, all of called datas in the code are in the geodatabase @Hornbydd . If you need i can send you geodatabase.

Comment: Failure to delete cursor might result in no features in a new dataset.

Comment: First thing in spatial analyst is extent. There is 100% chance that your destination point is outside source points raster created internally from 4 source points if extents don't match.